# Which fields are unique between two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have two lists (which I've put into two tables):

- `Table1` contains `field1` and is a list of identifiers,
- `Table2` contains `field2` and is another list of identifiers.

I want to run a query that will tell me what identifiers are unique between the two tables, i.e. they are either in `Table1.field1` only or in `Table2.field2` only, not in both.

Comment: `distinct`, `left-join` . so many options. What have you tried ?

Comment: That is one weird close vote, I for one do not agree. Reopen vote cast.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is

```
 (select * from #Table1
 except
 select * from #Table2)
union
 (select * from #Table2
 except
 select * from #Table1)
```

example:

```
Create table #Table1(Field1 varchar(100))
Create table #Table2(Field2 varchar(100))

Insert into #Table1 values
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')

Insert into #Table2 values
('e'),('f'),('c'),('d')
------------------------
(select * from #Table1
except
select * from #Table2)
union
(select * from #Table2
except
select * from #Table1)
```

=>

```
Field1
--------
a
b
c
d


Field2
--------
e
f
c
d

output :

Field1
--------
a
b
e
f
```

Answer (score 1):

The quirky (not the shortest, *maybe not the simplest either*) full set-based solution:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT field1
FROM Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT field2
FROM Table2 ) R1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT field2
FROM Table2
EXCEPT
SELECT field1
FROM Table1 ) R2
```

> 1st result set - Table1
>
> 2nd result set - Table2
>
> 3rd result set - Output - (unique identifiers - are either in field1 only or in field2 only, not in both)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this:

- Do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between the tables, linking `Table1.field1` to `Table2.field2`, and
- Have a `WHERE` clause to only select rows where either `Table1.field1` is NULL or `Table2.field2` is NULL

---

```
SELECT
    field=ISNULL(t1.field1, t2.field2)
FROM
    table1 AS t1
    FULL JOIN table2 AS t2 ON
        t2.field2=t1.field1
WHERE
    t1.field1 IS NULL OR
    t2.field2 IS NULL;
```

---

Another way to do this. The union of following result sets:

- Records of Table1 where field1 does not appear in Table2
- Records of Table2 where field2 does not appear in Table1

---

```
SELECT 
    field=field1 
FROM 
    table1 AS t1 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table2 AS t2 WHERE t2.field2=t1.field1)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    field=field2 
FROM 
    table2 AS t2 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1 WHERE t1.field1=t2.field2)
```